# Override the object type with a value

Tags: c#

I have a library which receive and return a string (I want create infinite numbers, but I'm simplifying the explanation).

I have my library with operator overloading and more source, but when I use the library:

```
MyType foo = new MyType("10");
MyType bar = foo + foo;
Console.WriteLine("{0}", bar.GetType());
Console.WriteLine("{0}", bar);
Console.WriteLine("{0}", bar.Value); // Redundant: the property "Value" has the value as string
```

The output is:

```
MyNamespace.MyType
MyNamespace.MyType // The object "bar" returns the object type
10
```

Well, but I want obtain "10" (bar.Value) using only the object name "bar":

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}", bar);
// I want the next output: 10
```

I tried doing changes with GetType() in the library (I found it's not possible override GetType()):

```
public new string GetType()
{
    return this.Value;
}
```

But this only works with "bar.GetType()" and not with "bar".

I think that is not possible in C#.

Answer (score 3):

This can easily be done by overriding [`Object.ToString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.object.tostring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
class MyType
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public override string ToString() { return this.Value; }
}
```

Test:

```
MyType m = new MyType("10");
Console.WriteLine(m);
```

Prints `10`.

Explenataion: When calling `WriteLine` the class´ `ToString`-method is called. If this method is not overridden within the type the default-implementation from `object` is used which will simply return the class´ type, in your case `MyNamespace.MyType`.

Comment: With this I've overrided toString() and it works, but in the source I use toString() and the behaviour is the default, not the overrided. It's geat, but why if I override it, don't change the behaviour in the source?